# Is it possible to connect to ArcSDE using QGIS?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, qgis

Is anyone aware of any plugins, or any other way to connect and view data from an ArcSDE database in QGIS desktop?

Comment: You can connect directly to the underlying database (PostGIS, Oracle or personal geodatabase), there should be no need (and maybe no way) to use ArcSDE as middle-ware.

Comment: How does MapServer do it? It's C and OGR based, and so is QGIS. Maybe there's a way like Matt Wilkie says.

Comment: If the spatial data is stored in `SDEBINARY` rather than the native oracle `SDO_GEOMETRY` or `ST_GEOMETRY` data types I think the only way to read it would be through ArcSDE? We have this issue with Geoserver where only the tables setup with `SDO_GEOMETRY` can be viewed with the Oracle connection, for our other legacy data we have to use the ArcSDE plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be possible to build a bridge through [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/)'s [ArcSDE driver](https://web.archive.org/web/20130531173324/http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_sde.html). It's not compiled in by default and needs some pieces of the ESRI SDE C API to connect. So to build this driver you need to have a copy of the SDE C API developer kit from ESRI. If memory serves, there is a pre-compiled sde driver floating around that can use ArcInfo Workstation installed on the local machine in place of the SDK.

**Sources:**

- http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/ESRI-ArcSDE-OGR-driver-td2026373.html#a2026373
- http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FWTools

Comment: I think the ArcInfo thing was only for reading ArcInfo binary coverages from GDAL. It has long since been deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

I am glad to say I have it working! I'm using QGIS 1.7 from OSGeo4W:

1. get the `ogr_sde.dll` (compile it from Tamas, you also need some ArcSDE SDK files)
2. replace the `gdal18.dll` used by qgis with the one you compiled above
3. put `ogr_sde.dll` in `C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\1.8`
4. create a `.vrt` file with your ArcSDE connection and feature classe details
5. add the vrt to QGIS, and voila!

Thing is, ogr takes a long time to connect. But viewing is OK. Just the connecting part is way too slow. Maybe someone will figure out a parameter for the connection to speed it up.

EDIT: forgot you also have to copy the following DLLs from your compilation in step 1: `xerces-c_28.dll`, `spatiallite.dll` and `openjpeg.dll`. You also need the ArcSDE libs: `sde.dll`, `sg.dll`, and `pe.dll`. Just put them in `C:\OSGeo4W\bin`.

EDIT 2: more info here: http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Connecting_to_ArcSDE_databases.

EDIT 3: the conection time is no longer a problem. Just a matter of correct connection string in the vrt. See the link for examples.

Comment: If you want SDE rasters, you want the gdal_sde.dll as well...

Comment: In response to a complaint, I just removed the Tamas link, that went to a good resource when it was originally posted but now goes to a 404 page that advertises some objectionable content. Do you know of a current site for it?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Postgres as your backend DB of ArcSDE, you have the option of storing spatial data in ST_Geometry (SDE spatial format) or PG_Geometry (PostGIS spatial format). If you store the data in PostGIS enabled DB and specify the PG_Geometry option when you import the data (optionally you can edit dbtune, I believe, to set PG_Geometry as the default), you will be able to connect to the data via an SDE connection or via a desktop client that can connect directly to PostGIS (such as QGIS)

Answer (score -3):

There is currently no way. If you were to use one of the Java based FOSS4G tools it should be possible using the SDE connector in geotools. I think this is how geoserver connects to SDE.

There is currently no data provider in the C++ world that plugs in to QGIS

Comment: Hey folks - before you downvote this more. Please look at the date when I answered this.

Comment: I suspect that this is getting downvoted because it is an answer that appears to be no longer valid.  If it is no longer valid, then I would recommend deleting it.  If it is still, or could be revised to once again become, current then that should help reverse the downvotes.