# How to connect QGIS to SDE?

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase

I read your amazing solution in this topic [Is it possible to connect to ArcSDE using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-arcsde-using-quantumgis).
Unfortunately I'm not so expert in open-source products (we use only Esri suite) and I need to ask you some things.
- How can I create a .ovr file with my SDE connection?
- How can I add it to QGIS?

Answer (score 7):

You can get `ogr_sde.dll` from the [MapServer download](http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/index.phtml?page=downloads.html).  If you grab the zip file, it will be in `gdalplugins\ignored\` directory.

Instructions for connecting to SDE through GDAL/OGR can be found [here](https://www.gdal.org/drv_sde.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, after installing QGIS 1.7 I replaced and added the files but an error occurs: cfitsio.dll not found, a new installation is required and Qgis doesn't start. If I use the old dll Qgis starts but I can't understand how to set the SDE Connection. THANKS a lot for help me and sorry, but as I said, I'm new in these stuffs and I'd need step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 3):

[Quantum GIS Desktop - Connecting to ArcSDE databases - QGIS Issue Tracking](http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Connecting_to_ArcSDE_databases)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [Quantum GIS Desktop - Connecting to ArcSDE databases - QGIS Issue Tracking](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Connecting_to_ArcSDE_databases)
and [Quantum GIS Forum: ogr/gdal plugins for ArcSDE](http://forum.qgis.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8835) and I got data out of SDE into QGIS using a .vrt file.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.