# Connecting ArcSDE to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase, qgis-plugins, vrt

I have a need to be able to connect to and edit ArcSDE data in QGIS.

This question has been asked before as:

- [Is it possible to connect to ArcSDE using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240)
- https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Connecting_to_ArcSDE_databases

  and apparently is possible, but the instructions are just not specific enough for me to follow...

I was able to get the sde-9.3/ogr_SDE.dll from the MapServer zip download and place it in C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalplugins, but then what?

I've read I need to compile it, but how and with what?

I've read I need to create a vrt file.

Is there a tool that creates a vrt file or should I just open notepad and write one?

Then how do I add the vrt file to QGIS?

Comment: did you make any progress with this? we're about to get ArcGIS for Server installed here and I've got several QGIS users that will need to view and edit data. We use both SQL and PostgreSQL databases. Thanks

Comment: No, I tried but moved onto other things.

Comment: What database is your SDE in? If its SQL Server I can most likely help. We are able to connect to ArcSDE through the add MSSQL Spatial Layer connection. Just enter the database credentials and it should log in. Also what version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Still need an answer to this? I have a way to make it work and can document it out for users.

Comment: Sql Server Express 2008 and QGIS 2.4

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  To progress I think we need you to list the steps you performed successfully as a lead up to describing precisely where you get stuck.  Asking for more specific details to be provided is too broad for focussed Q&A.